# Migrating from spring-data-elasticsearch 4.x to 5.x

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Hello dear community,

I am currently migrating some ES queries from spring-data-elasticsearch 4.x to 5.x and have therefore switched from rhlc to elc. Now I am faced with the problem that some queries have to be rebuilt, but I don't know exactly how to rewrite or cast them so that they are compatible with the new client. Perhaps there are people here who have more experience with ES and could help me here. Would be very happy about it.

1. How can I extend NativeQuerys with BoolQueryBuilders or how could I rewrite such queries so that they are equivalent to the elc?
2. How can I extend NativeQueryBuilders with matchQuerys?
3. How do aggregate on the elc?

```
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.NativeQuery;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.elc.NativeQueryBuilder;


//1.
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    boolQueryBuilder.must().addAll(Arrays.asList(
      QueryBuilders.matchQuery("mappingId", mappingId),
      QueryBuilders.matchQuery("artId", articleId)
    ));
    Query query = new NativeQueryBuilder().withQuery(**boolQueryBuilder**).withPageable(Pageable.unpaged()).build();

//2.
NativeQuery query = new NativeQueryBuilder()
      .withQuery(**QueryBuilders.matchQuery("artId", articleId)**)
      .build();

//3.
NativeQuery query = 
new NativeQueryBuilder().withQuery(boolQueryBuilderForDealer).withPageable(Pageable.unpaged()).build();
    query.addAggregation(**AggregationBuilders.terms(aggregation).field(aggregation).size(100)**);
```

Casting type, migrating from hlrc to elc

Comment: The documentation for the Elasticsearch Java client is available at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/index.html